# How to reduce vendor.js file and main.js file in angular 15 with NX workspace?

Tags: angular, nx-workspace

[image: this image is my network both file take more size like 9 mb +]

I want to reduce size of vendo.js and main.js so improve  rendring time of login page and entire application

I was add optimization : true in project.json but its not work in my NX workspace project

I am using angular 15 with NX workspace

SO How can I achive that In my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Employ tree-shaking to remove unused code.
2. Use code splitting to load modules on demand.
3. Optimize third-party dependencies and use modular builds.
4. Minify your JavaScript code.
5. Analyze bundles to identify large dependencies.
6. Use production builds and Angular's optimizations.
7. Enable compression on the server.
8. Regularly update dependencies for performance improvements.